# Inline CSS on NodeJS Babel Server

Tags: css, node.js, inline, babeljs

I made a previous post vaguely describing my issues, and unfortunately it got disregarded. My issue is that I'm trying to inline my CSS into my HTML when it is rendered on the server-side. All of the tutorials only show solutions to make external files. I want the traditional 'style-loader' inline behavior.  I'm using Webpack, React, NodeJS, & Babel.

Webpack Config:

```
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin = require("optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin");
const UglifyJsPlugin = require("uglifyjs-webpack-plugin");
const CompressionPlugin = require("compression-webpack-plugin");
const devMode = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
module.exports = {
    entry: './src/js/app.js',
    output: {
        path: __dirname + "/src/js/",
        filename: 'app.bundle.js'
    },
    mode: 'development',
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin({
            filename: devMode ? '[name].css' : '[name].[hash].css',
            chunkFilename: devMode ? '[id].css' : '[id].[hash].css',
        })
    ],
    optimization: {
        minimizer: [
            new UglifyJsPlugin({
                cache: true,
                parallel: true,
                extractComments: true
            }),
            new OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin({}),
            new CompressionPlugin()
        ]
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(jsx|js)?$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                use: [{
                    loader: "babel-loader",
                    options: {
                        cacheDirectory: true,
                        presets: ['react', 'es2015']
                    }
                }]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(sc|c)ss$/,
                use: [
                    devMode ? 'style-loader' : ExtractTextPlugin.loader,
                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader',
                        options: {
                            modules: true,
                            importLoaders: 1,
                            localIdentName: 'ko_[sha1:hash:hex:3]'
                        }
                    },
                    'sass-loader'
                ],
            }
        ]
    },
};
```

.babelrc

```
{
    "presets": [
        "es2015",
        "react"
    ],
    "plugins": [
        [
            "css-modules-transform",
            {
                "generateScopedName": "ko_[sha1:hash:hex:3]",
                "extensions": [
                    ".scss"
                ]
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```